# Can I add support for native DSD on a USB DAC without compiling from source?

Tags: 16.04, sound, kernel, compiling

I have a Topping DX7s DAC that is capable of native DSD512 playback. It defaults to DoP on the default Ubuntu kernel, but I have been able to get native DSD playback by adding the vendor and device ID's to `../sound/usb/quirks.c`:

Specifically:

```
    case USB_ID(0x152a, 0x8750): /* Topping DX7s */
    case USB_ID(0x20b1, 0x000a): /* Gustard DAC-X20U */
    case USB_ID(0x20b1, 0x2009): /* DIYINHK DSD DXD 384kHz USB to I2S/DSD */
    case USB_ID(0x20b1, 0x2023): /* JLsounds I2SoverUSB */
    case USB_ID(0x20b1, 0x3023): /* Aune X1S 32BIT/384 DSD DAC */
    case USB_ID(0x2616, 0x0106): /* PS Audio NuWave DAC */
        if (fp->altsetting == 3)
            return SNDRV_PCM_FMTBIT_DSD_U32_BE;
        break;
```

and then compiling the kernel.

Is there any way to enable something like this without compiling the kernel from source? I'd like to stick with the most recent kernel without having to compile every release.

Comment: I submitted a patch to the upstream linux kernel and it was accepted. But, it would still be great to have an efficient way to implement this outside of building a kernel from source for each release. I imagine it will be a (long) while before the changes make it to a 16.04 kernel.